# Best way to get part of a number from a file name with SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I need to extract part of a name from text files in SQL.  The file names are always something like this:

```
AA_123456789_MoreText_MMDDYYYYHHMM.txt
```

What I need to get is between the first and second underscore.  This part varies in character length.  Usually they are all numbers, but sometimes includes a letter in it.

Any ideas on the best way to handle this in SQL?

Comment: You need to look at  the `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` functions

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution based on tokenization.

This way you can select any token in any position in a string.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('AA_123456789_MoreText_MMDDYYYYHHMM.txt'),
('BB_770_MoreText_MMDDYYYYHHMM.xml');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '_'
    , @position INT = 2;

SELECT ID, tokens
    , c.value('(/root/r[sql:variable("@position")]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Token
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------+
| ID |                 tokens                 |   Token   |
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | AA_123456789_MoreText_MMDDYYYYHHMM.txt | 123456789 |
|  2 | BB_770_MoreText_MMDDYYYYHHMM.xml       |       770 |
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(filename,
                 CHARINDEX('_', filename) + 1,
                 CHARINDEX('_', filename, CHARINDEX('_', filename, 1)) - 2)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

In plain English, the above substring operation says to take all content after the first underscore, but before the second underscore.